# How can I get the name value, multi-layered JSON value

Tags: json, swift

how can I get value of the name. thank you!
the webservice returns this json:

```
{
    "msg":"ok",
    "content":[{"id":"123","status":"10","date":"2014-08-20","name":"abc"}]
}
```

How can I get the name value, multi-layered JSON value.
i can get msg value,but name value... What method

Answer (score 0):

That JSON is ugly. This is how you can get the `"name"`.

```
import Foundation


let jsonTestString = "{\"msg\":\"ok\",\"content\":[{\"id\":\"123\",\"status\":\"10\",\"date\":\"2014-08-20\",\"name\":\"abc\"}]}"
let jsonTestData = jsonTestString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)

if let data = jsonTestData {
    let jsonDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: nil) as [String : AnyObject]
    let content = jsonDictionary["content"] as AnyObject? as? [[String : String]]
    let name = content?.first?["name"]
    println(name ?? "There is no name.") // prints abc.
}
```

Pay attention to this line:

```
let content = jsonDictionary["content"] as AnyObject? as? [[String : String]]
```

We should be able to conditionally downcast directly to `[[String : String]]` like this:

```
let content = jsonDictionary["content"] as? [[String : String]]
```

It's a [known bug](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1018351#1018351).